# How to show an icon on hover or click, again hide it on mouse out or click other list with ngFor angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a simple list containing few rows coming from a loop.When ever I click or hover on any rows it becomes active, again on clicking other row,current row will be active and previous will be inactive. Till now working fine.But in the row there is some icons which I need to show or hide same as active.When I hover/click, those icons will show and again hide on mouse out or click on next row.Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li  *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': clickedIndex == i}" (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i"><span>{{row.items}}</span>---><span>Icon1</span><span>Icon2</span></li>
  </ul>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  clickedIndex: number = 0


  groups = [{ "id": 1, "name": "pencils", "items": "red pencil", "Status": [{ "id": 1, "name": "green" }, { "id": 2, "name": "red" }, { "id": 3, "name": "yellow" }], "loc": [{ "id": 1, "name": "loc 1" }, { "id": 2, "name": "loc 2" }, { "id": 3, "name": "loc 3" }] }, { "id": 2, "name": "rubbers", "items": "big rubber", "Status": [{ "name": "green" }, { "name": "red" }], "loc": [{ "name": "loc 2" }, { "name": "loc 3" }] }, { "id": 3, "name": "rubbers1", "items": "big rubber1", "Status": [{ "name": "green" }, { "name": "red" }], "loc": [{ "name": "loc 2" }, { "name": "loc 3" }] }]
}
```

### app.component.css

```
.active{
background:red;
color:#FFf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using *ngIf `(*ngIf="clickedIndex == i")` for both icons in spans

```
<ul>
  <li  *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': clickedIndex == i}" (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex : clickedIndex = i"><span>{{row.items}}</span>---><span *ngIf="clickedIndex == i">Icon1</span><span *ngIf="clickedIndex == i">Icon2</span></li>
  </ul>
```

working code for reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hppkxl?file=src/app/app.component.html

To show/hide icons on hover/click, use mouseenter event with another variabled hoveredIndex

```
<ul>
  <li (mouseenter) ="hoveredIndex == i? hoveredIndex = null : hoveredIndex = i" *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': clickedIndex == i}" (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i"><span>{{row.items}}</span>--->
  <ng-container><span  *ngIf="hoveredIndex == i || clickedIndex == i">Icon1</span><span *ngIf="hoveredIndex == i || clickedIndex == i">Icon2</span>
  </ng-container>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

working code for reference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddytef?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working fine but on hover icons are not showing

Comment: updated answer with working code for reference -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjufzc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for answer ,there is one issue here if you click again on active list, its color and icons are both hiding after removing the cursor but its should not

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER, please confirm "hide on mouse out or click on next row" this line, please provide scenarios and expected output

Comment: The row which is active,if you click again on active row it should not inactive or it should not hide icons,apart from everything is fine

Comment: are you looking for something liek this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddytef?file=src/app/app.component.html   Changed click event to (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex : clickedIndex = i"

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to achieve this. Set a new variable, say `hoveredIndex` to `i` on `mouseenter` and set it to `null` on `mouseleave`. Then just add the necessary conditions to your `ngIf`

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" 
        [ngClass]="{'active': clickedIndex == i || hoveredIndex === i}" 
        (click)="clickedIndex = i" 
        (mouseenter)="hoveredIndex = i" 
        (mouseleave)="hoveredIndex = null">
        <span>{{row.items}}</span>
        ---><span *ngIf="clickedIndex == i || hoveredIndex === i">Icon1</span>
        <span *ngIf="clickedIndex == i || hoveredIndex === i">Icon2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-active-on-hover).

Comment: Thanks for answer ,there is one issue here if you click again on active list, its color and icons are both hiding after removing the cursor but its should not

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. All you have to do is change your `click` function to `(click)="clickedIndex = i"` since you don't want the ability to unclick an active `li`. I have updated my answer and StackBlitz accordingly as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Angular. You can use `pseudo` element `:hover` on `css`

Comment: in that case icons will not be visible right on background color change will happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-container` with `*ngIf` to show/hide the span icons.

Try like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': clickedIndex == i}" (click)="clickedIndex == i? clickedIndex = null : clickedIndex = i">
        <span>{{row.items}}</span>---> 
        <ng-container *ngIf="clickedIndex == i">
           <span>Icon1</span><span>Icon2</span>
        </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-58dnby)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working fine but on hover icons are not showing